# How to draw a view over a GLkit view on iOS5/Ipad

Tags: ios5, opengl-es, uistoryboard

I´m creating a GLK view on iOS5.

First, i create the context.

```
GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
view.context = self.context;
view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

[self setupGL];
```

Second, i draw a triangle moving.

This works.

Now, i want to create a view over the GLKview. So, i used the Storyboard, to draw a View (HUDView) with background red, and i put it over the main view. When i run the app, only openGL appear, i assume that red background view is drawing behind GLKView. Why?

I have tried to use on Hudview -> viewDidLoad

```
[self bringSubviewToFront:self];
```

But the problem nothing happen.

Any idea how could i solve this problem????

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a sample that solve the problem. [Glfun](https://bitbucket.org/pyanfield/testios4/src/b92b03d3083c/GLFun/) is a sample where a openGL layer is drawn, and you can add a hud view over it. Hopes help people :D